Why is maven not installed? Command 'mvn' not found
I a on Ubuntu 24.04.
I downloaded 3.9.9 form
maven3 official
than unpacked and moved to usr/bin/.
/usr/bin/maven$ ls -lrt
total 48
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  1279 Aug 14 09:48 README.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  5034 Aug 14 09:48 NOTICE
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 18920 Aug 14 09:48 LICENSE
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root  4096 Aug 14 09:48 conf
drwxrwxr-x 2 root root  4096 Dec 30 09:23 bin
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root  4096 Dec 30 09:23 boot
drwxr-xr-x 4 root root  4096 Dec 30 09:23 lib

mvn -- version shows
Command 'mvn' not found, but can be installed with:
sudo apt install maven

Why mvn is not found?

Add to PATH /usr/bin/maven/bin

ok,yes it works now.

See also https://maven.apache.org/install.html

You need to add the path to the binary in variable PATH. The command will be something like:
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/bin/maven/bin

and you can add it in .bashrc file to have in for next login/reboot
